# Is FSAL for Oracle Forms 12c compatible with Java 9+

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c

We have an Oracle forms 12c application that is launched using FSAL. The launch script looks like this:

```
java -jar %FSAL_HOME%\frmsal.jar -url "http://frmserver:9001/forms/frmservlet?config=MyApp" -t 30000"
```

It was working well using Java 8 but it fails to launch using Java 10 or Java 11 (Did not tried using Java 9).  Does anyone managed to launch `frmsal.jar` using these Java versions ?

This is the printout:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp (file://mirapp02/FTP/Forms12c/frmsal.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp.getArchivesFromServer(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp.run(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.forms.saa.FormsStandAloneApp.main(Unknown Source)
```